# How to correct TypeError: execute() takes from 2 to 4 positional arguments but 5 were given?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-connector-python

I am really struggling here .. so immediate help would be appreciated. Have to submit a project tomorrow. If this question is repeated please do send me the link for the answer.

```
if user_input==2:
    number=int(input("Enter number of tickets you want to book-"))
    for b in range(0,number):
        passengername=input("Enter name of passenger-")
        starting_station=input("Enter name of station from where passenger will board train-")
        destination=input("Enter name of station passenger wishes to reach-")
                    
        print("Ticket Booked!")
        mydb=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="",database="railways")
        mycursor=mydb.cursor()
        mycursor.execute("select train_no from route_fare where from_station=%s",(starting_station,), " and to_station=%s",(destination,))
        for w in mycursor:
            train_number_p=w
```

**THE OUTPUT:**

```
Enter number of tickets you want to book-1
Enter name of passenger-Ollie
Enter name of station from where passenger will board train-Jaipur Railway Station
Enter name of station passenger wishes to reach-Churu Railway Station
Ticket Booked!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 14, in <module>
    mycursor.execute("select train_no from route_fare where from_station=%s",(starting_station,), " and to_station=%s",(destination,))
TypeError: execute() takes from 2 to 4 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

Comment: Untested but try `mycursor.execute("select train_no from route_fare where from_station=%s and to_station=%s",(starting_station,destination))`

Comment: This error message is really confusing for beginners. `mycursor` is an instance of a class. Any instances implicitly hand methods the instance as the first argument when called like `instance.method()` or in your case `mycursor.execute()`. so you are actually handing `execute()` 5 arguments. And as @JustinEzequiel pointed out, the reason your second argument is a tuple, is so that you can hand it multiple parameters.

Comment: I could not find better docs but start with https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html to see where you went wrong.

Comment: Thank you! the above code fixed it!